# How to convert Unicode escaped characters to utf8?

Tags: c, encoding, utf-8

I saw the other questions about the subject but all of them were missing important details:
I want to convert `\u00252F\u00252F\u05de\u05e8\u05db\u05d6` to utf8. I understand that you look through the stream for \u followed by four hex which you convert to bytes. The problems are as follows:

1. I heard that sometimes you look for 4 bytes after and sometimes 6 bytes after, is this correct? If so, then how do you determine which it is? E.g. is `\u00252F` 4 or 6 bytes?
2. In the case of `\u0025` this maps to one byte instead of two (0x25), why? Is the four hex supposed to represent utf16 which i am supposed to convert to utf8?
3. How do I know whether the text is supposed to be the literal characters `\u0025` or the unicode sequence? Does that mean that all backslashes must be escaped in the stream?
4. Lastly, am I being stupid in doing this by hand when I can use iconv to do this for me?

Comment: "then how do you determine which it is?" That's what we should be asking *you*. Is `\u00252F` *always* one single character, or is it the character U+0025 followed by `2` (U+0032) followed by `F` (U+0046)? "Is the four hex supposed to represent utf16 which i am supposed to convert to utf8?" Again, how can we know? Where does this data come from?

Comment: In most escaping systems that use `\u`, exactly 4 hexadecimal digits must follow the `\u` and are considered to make up one UTF-16 code unit.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I am asking from a parsing standpoint, i see the data `\u00252F` how can i determine whether it is `\u0025`+2F or `\u00252F`?

Comment: @chacham15 By knowing what it is you are parsing.

Comment: @chacham15: It depends on the **specification** governing the format of the input. Fundmanetally, \u00252F does not represent either; it represents the backslash character, followed by a lowercase u, followed by the digits 0, 0, 2, 5, 2, and the letter F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `iconv` interfaces at your disposal, you can simply convert the `\u0123\uABCD` etc. sequences to an array of bytes `01 23 AB CD` ..., replacing any unescaped ASCII characters with a 00 byte followed by the ASCII byte, then run the array through `iconv` with a conversion descriptor obtained by `iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-16-BE")`.

Of course you can also do it much more efficiently working directly with the input yourself, but that requires reading and understanding the Unicode specification of UTF-16 and UTF-8.

Comment: so, to put your response in terms of my question: 1: always 4 bytes, 2: it is utf16, 3: yes, 4: only for the escaped utf16 character. Is that correct?

Comment: No. 1. that depends on the format of your input, which you must know. 2. It's almost surely UTF-16, but that also depends on the format of your input. 3. Again, it depends on the format of your input. I'm telling you what to do if you know `\u` is to be interpreted as an escape, but that may be a wrong assumption. 4. There's no standard way to `iconv` to work directly with the escaped form; **some** `iconv` implementations may support it directly as an input, but I wouldn't rely on that in programs intended to be portable.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. So what you are saying is that this escape is a common pattern to escape many different formats into ascii and in order to convert it into utf8 I need to know which format was escaped into ascii?

Comment: Yes. For example, C99 has a `\u`, Java has a `\u`, JavaScript has a `\u`, JSON has a `\u` (presumably compatible with JavaScript), etc...

Answer (score 0):

In some conventions (like C++11 string literals), you parse a specific number of hex digits, like four after `\u` and eight after `\U`.  That may or may not be the convention with the input you provided, but it seems a reasonable guess.  Other styles, like C++'s `\x` you parse as many hex digits as you can find after the `\x`, which means that you have to jump through some hoops if you do want to put a literal hex digit immediately after one of these escaped characters.

Once you have all the values, you need to know what encoding they're in (e.g., UTF-16 or UTF-32) and what encoding you want (e.g., UTF-8).  You then use a function to create a new string in the new encoding.  You can write such a function (if you know enough about both encoding formats), or you can use a library.  Some operating systems may provide such a function, but you might want to use a third-party library for portability.

Comment: The first sentence is wrong. C++11 string literals consider *exactly* four digits after `\u`, *exactly* eight digits after `\U`, and as many as possible after `\x`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes:  Thanks.  I was confusing `\x` with `\u` and `\U`.  I've corrected the answer.